# resolve path to layout

Tags: templates, groovy

I am trying to load a layout's   '.tpl'   file while generating an HTML template.

In my code if I give path of the file as below it works :

```
layout  'myfile.tpl',
```

But if I give a local path , it doesn't work , though the local path is correct:

```
layout  'C:/Users/jane/Desktop/2018/myfile.tpl' ,
```

I get the below error :

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Unable to load template:C:/Users/jane/Desktop/2018/myfile.tpl
java.io.IOException: Unable to load template:C:/Users/jane/Desktop/2018/myfile.tpl
    at GeneratedMarkupTemplate0.run(GeneratedMarkupTemplate0:195)
    at testing.run(testing.groovy:277)
```

Is the template engine not able to resolve the path ?? The local path is correct.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. This invalidates the answer posted below.

Answer (score 2):

The template engine looks on the classpath

https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-templates/src/main/groovy/groovy/text/markup/MarkupTemplateEngine.java#L314

So you can't just link to a random file in your machine... Which is probably a good thing

Comment: Thats correct that the engine looks on the classpath . But if I say want to give path to a .tpl file in some folder , after deploying in a certain VM . That would be a limitation .